# Caching of synchronous connection

Tags: ios, caching, nsurlconnection, synchronous

I've encountered next problem with next method

```
+ (NSString *)sendRequest:(NSMutableURLRequest *)request {

NSHTTPURLResponse *response;
NSError *error;
NSData *responseData;
[request setCachePolicy:NSURLRequestReturnCacheDataElseLoad];

responseData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:reqq returningResponse:&response error:&error];

//actions with responseData.
}
```

I noticed that data is never cached for this requests. Cache remains empty. Is there any way to cache response data with synchronous connection or should I redesign the way I receive data to asynchronous connection?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

[NSURLCache](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Classes/NSURLCache_Class/Reference/Reference.html) implements the caching of responses to URL load requests by mapping NSURLRequest objects to NSCachedURLResponse objects. NSURLCache provides a composite in-memory and on-disk caching mechanism for URL requests to your application.

Use this code in your `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` method and set the http request cache policy

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application 
    didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions 
{
  NSURLCache *URLCache = [[NSURLCache alloc] initWithMemoryCapacity:4 * 1024 * 1024 
                                                       diskCapacity:20 * 1024 * 1024 
                                                           diskPath:nil];
  [NSURLCache setSharedURLCache:URLCache];
}
```

refer [this](http://nshipster.com/nsurlcache/) blog for more info

Comment: [NSURLCache sharedURLCache] is already set up. But looks like not this is the reason of problem